# Redefine a prototype is not possible? Why?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing some testing trying to redefine (as example) AudioContext.prototype, but I can't.

For example, using the browser console, I can't set AudioContext.prototype as for example an string "test".

`input --> AudioContext.prototype = "test"
 output --> "test"
 input --> AudioContext.prototype
 output --> AudioContext {suspend: ƒ, close: ƒ, getOutputTimestamp: ƒ, constructor: ƒ, …}`

When I try to access to it, nothing has changed.

On the other hand, I can modify its properties like AudioContext.prototype.close without problems but not the actual prototype.

I'm sure I'm missing something there.

Comment: prototype is not writable. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Comment: wow thanks. That solves my issue.

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings `Object.prototype` is not writable. The page you linked says nothing about `AudioContext.prototype`. (But yes, that one isn't writable either)

Comment: @Bergi `AudioContext` is derived from `BaseAudioContext` which is derived from `EventTarget` which is inherited from `Object` and because this is a comment. Hence.

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings No, it does not inherit from `Object`, it inherits from `Function.prototype`. `AudioContext.prototype` does inherit (through some chains) from `Object.prototype`.

Comment: @Bergi You said it does and it doesn't.

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings The `AudioContext` constructor does not inherit from the `Object` constructor, so the latter ones `.prototype` property is not relevant for writing the former ones `.prototype` property.

Comment: @Bergi Clear. Thank You